# What is a best way to organise the complex couchdb view (sql-like query)?

Tags: sql, performance, couchdb

In my application I need a SQL-like query of the documents. The big picture is that there is a page with a paginated table showing the couchdb documents of a certain "type". I have about 15 searchable columns like timestamp, customer name, the us state, different numeric fields, etc. All of these columns are orderable, also there is a filter form allowing the user to filter by each of the fields.

For a more concrete below is a typical query which is a result by a customer setting some of the filter options and following to the second page. Its written in a pseodo-sql code, just to explain the problem:

`timestamp > last_weeks_monday_epoch AND timestamp < this_weeks_monday_epoch AND marked_as_test = False AND dataspace="production" AND fico > 650 
SORT BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 15
SKIP 15`

This would be a trivial problem if I were using any sql-like database, but couchdb is way more fun ;) To solve this I've created a view with the following structure of the emitted rows:

`key: [field, value], id: doc._id, value: null`

Now, to resolve the example query above I need to perform a bunch of queries:

- `{startkey: ["timestamp", last_weeks_monday_epoch], endkey: ["timestamp", this_weeks_monday_epoch]}`, the `*_epoch` here are integers epoch timestamps,
- `{key: ["marked_as_test", False]}`,
- `{key: ["dataspace", "production"]}`,
- `{startkey: ["fico", 650], endkey: ["fico", {}]}`

Once I have the results of the queries above I calculate intersection of the sets of document IDs and apply the sorting using the result of timestamp query. Than finally I can apply the slice resolving the document IDs of the rows 15-30 and download their content using bulk get operation.

Needless to say, its not the fastest operation. Currently the dataset I'm working with is roughly 10K documents big. I can already see that the part when I'm calculating the intersection of the sets can take like 4 seconds, obviously I need to optimize it further. I'm afraid to think, how slow its going to get in a few months when my dataset doubles, triples, etc.

Ok, so having explained the situation I'm at, let me ask the actual questions.

1. Is there a better, more natural way to reach my goal without loosing the flexibility of the tool?
2. Is the view structure I've used optimal ? At some point I was considering using a separate map() function generating the value of each field. This would result in a smaller b-trees but more work of the view server to generate the index. Can I benefit this way ?
3. The part of algorithm where I have to calculate intersections of the big sets just to later get the slice of the result bothers me. Its not a scalable approach. Does anyone know a better algorithm for this ?

Comment: Ad 3. After writing down this question I figured that instead of sorting the result of the intersection using the timestamp index as the sorting key I can iterate over the timestamp index and check if the elements are a member of the result set. This way I don't have to sort the whole big set because I can stop as soon as I have enough elements in the response. This gives the improvement if 7s down to 0.02 s for requesting a page of 15 elemetns for a dataset of 10K. (Booya!)

Answer (score 1):

Having map function:

```
function(doc){
    if(doc.marked_as_test) return;
    emit([doc.dataspace, doc.timestamp, doc.fico], null):
}
```

You can made similar request:

```
 http://localhost:5984/db/_design/ddoc/_view/view?startkey=["production", :this_weeks_monday_epoch]&endkey=["production", :last_weeks_monday_epoch, 650]&descending=true&limit=15&skip=15
```

However, you should pass `:this_weeks_monday_epoch` and `:last_weeks_monday_epoch` values from the client side (I believe they are some calculable variables on database side, right?)

If you don't care about `dataspace` field (e.g. it's always constant), you may move it into the map function code instead of having it in query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The query range you proposed will include a very different set of rows. First of all, this will include all the different values of the dataspace and fico fields. Also you cannot extend this query by more keys. I need the possibility to filter and sort by the each of the ~14 index fields I have. The key structure like this allows to only query the range of parameter in the last element of the key with the previous elements fixed.

Comment: @MarekKowalski you're right. I was wrong with params order. Constants should go first. And yes, you cannot have same flexibility of SQL for views: views are solving specific task, not generic, so adding one more parameter may be a problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CouchDB is a good fit for the general solution to your problem. However, there are two basic ways you can mitigate the ways CouchDB fits the problem.

1. Write/generate a bunch of `map()` functions that use each separate column as the key (for even better read/query performance, you can even do combinatoric approaches). That way you can do smart filtering and sorting, making use of a bunch of different indices over the data. On the other hand, this will cost extra disk space and index caching performance.
2. Try to find out which of the filters/sort orders your users actually use, and optimize for those. It seems unlikely that each combination of filters/sort orders is used equally, so you should be able to find some of the most-used patterns and write view functions that are optimal for those patterns.

I like the second option better, but it really depends on your use case. This is one of those things SQL engines have been pretty good at traditionally.